# Parse-server docker inject package.json

Tags: docker, parse-platform, package.json, parse-server

Hello guys i try to install Parse-Server on my home server ( unraid ) with docker container from hub docker https://hub.docker.com/r/parseplatform/parse-server
Do somebody know how to inject package.json to install npm modules

I tried to move file to cloud/package.json and i get error: Cannot find module
and i have correct path to cloudCode folder because cloudColde runs.

Please help

here are my parameters

```
source: parseplatform/parse-server
name: parse-server
Post Argumente: --appId xxx --masterKey xxxx --databaseURI mongodb://192.168.178.27:27017/test --cloud /parse-server/cloud/main.js --mountGraphQL
-v config : /mnt/user/appdata/parse-server/config/
-v cloud: /mnt/user/appdata/parse-server/cloud/
-p: 1337

#Folder structure
cloud/
 -main.js
 -package.json
config/
 -configuration.json
```

Comment: Have you tried to follow this? https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server#docker-container

Comment: thank you for your answer @DaviMacêdo yes i do. its the same problem. Error: Cannot find module.  i try again to run container:  docker run --name my-parse-server -v mypath/config/:/parse-server/cloud  -p 1337:1337 --link my-mongo:mongo -d parse-server --appId APPLICATION_ID --masterKey MASTER_KEY --databaseURI mongodb://mongo/test --cloud /parse-server/cloud/main.js

Comment: and here is nothing about cloud code package  github.com/parse-community/parse-server#docker-container

Answer (score 0):

Guys i have a solution  if you want to inject node modules to your docker container

you have to define in your local cloud folder package,json with your modules you want to.
you have to run “npm install” to install your dependencies.
3 run your docker container with -v mypath/config/:/parse-server/cloud --cloud /parse-server/cloud/main.js
Ready.

Many thanks to developers from Parse Server it is sooooo great system. I LOVE IT ❤️